# Missing logic in Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've changed the condition to null expecting the trigger doesn't run the script if the updated cell value ( Approved/Rejected/Duplicate)is removed (Post removal the cell value will be "")

Here is the updated Script:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){ 
if (e.range.columnStart == 5 || e.value !="" ) {
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,5).getValues();
let EmployeeName = rData[0][1];
let Reviewer = rData[0][3];
let Status = rData[0][4];
var ccmail = "raghavrocking6@gmail.com";
var UpdateEmail =
('<html>'+ ` '<body>'+ '<head>'+ '<style>table, th,tr{border: 2px solid black;}</style>'+'</head>'+ '<tr style="background-color:#d3ecdc;"><td width=500 height=auto; colspan=6><br>``
Hi '+EmployeeName+',<br><br> Your suggestion has been '+Status+' by '+Reviewer+'<br> you can check the comments here <br><br>Regards,<br>"Rajanee"<br><br></td></tr>'+
'</body>'+ '</html>')
 MailApp.sendEmail({to: EmployeeName,subject: 'Idea Status!',htmlBody: UpdateEmail, name:'Ideas',cc:ccmail});
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the trigger a Simple Trigger (just naming your function onEdit), or is it an Installable Trigger (assigned in the Triggers tab of the Apps Script UI)? I believe operations that involve things like MailApp require an Installable Trigger. Additionally, do you see any errors in the executions log? That should give you a clue as to whether there's a problem with the script. Also, what value are you expecting in Cell F5? It looks like if the value is Approved, Rejected or Duplicate, your email will not be sent, as your if returns early.

Comment: It's an an installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet and I do not see any errors in the execution log. 

The value in cell 5 is manually edited to ether Approved or Rejected or Duplicate and an email must be sent  using the installable trigger through MailApp method

Unfortunately, I am unable to debug the code and make corrections to it

Comment: FYI, the project contains ALL your functions. In your case, you renamed your project: "onEdit". I don't think that this would generate any errors, but generally one chooses a less function-specific name for the project. Second, a function called `onEdit(e)` will be automatically recognised and assigned a "Simple" trigger; as @Cooper points out, if you actually need that function to have an "Installable" trigger then its best to rename it to something other than `onEdit` otherwise your function will receive two triggers (the simple trigger and the installable trigger)  and chaos will ensue.

Comment: I have changed the function name. I understand the trigger runs if an edit is made in the cell - Approved/Duplicate/Rejected, but if I remove the status in the cell, the email still triggers as its an edit made the cell by ignoring the condition 
if (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value =="Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate")

I'd wish to restrict the email to be sent only if the cell has a value. I used the return statement, but the trigger won't work

if (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value =="Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate") return;

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @great_pan, you should add an installable trigger like this:[image]

And try with the code a little bit modified. Run it once from the console in order to accept permissions (yes, in the console it will run an error, but you'll be able to accept them and then try it when you edit that column):

```
function onEdit(e){
   if (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value =="Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate"){
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues();
   let EmployeeName = rData[0][1];
   let Reviewer = rData[0][3];
   let Comments = rData[0][4];
   let Status = rData[0][6];
   var ccmail = "raghavrocking6@gmail.com";
  var UpdateEmail =
(  '<html>'+
   '<body>'+
              '<head>'+
              '<style>table, th,tr{border: 2px solid black;}</style>'+
              '</head>'+  
                          '<tr style="background-color:#d3ecdc;"><td width=500 height=auto; colspan=6><br>Hi '+EmployeeName+',<br><br> Your suggestion has been '+Status+' by '+Reviewer+'<br> you can check the comments here: ' +Comments+ '<br><br>Regards,<br>"Rajanee"<br><br></td></tr>'+
'</body>'+
'</html>')
 MailApp.sendEmail({to: EmployeeName,subject: 'Idea Status!',htmlBody: UpdateEmail, name:'Ideas',cc:ccmail});
 }
}
```

Comment: You should change the name of the function. As it stands now your function will receive two triggers ( the simple trigger and the installable trigger)

Comment: I have changed the function name. I understand the trigger runs if an edit is made in the cell - Approved/Duplicate/Rejected, but if I remove the status in the cell, the email still triggers as its an edit made the cell by ignoring the condition if (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value =="Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate") I'd wish to restrict the email to be sent only if the cell has a value. I used the return statement, but the trigger won't work if (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value =="Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate") return;

Comment: (e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.value != "") Try this without the return. (Return will close the script so the mail won't be sent)

Comment: I tried the condition, but whenever I remove updated value (Approved/Rejected/Duplicate) in the cell and email is sent; expected as the trigger is set. However, I need t restrict and email when I modify the cell value to null

Comment: Could you update the post with your full actual code?

Comment: I have updated the actual code in the post.

Comment: Sorry, spotted it. Change || with &&

Comment: Didn't observed that you were saying "or" instead of "and" in the first place

Comment: Changed it to - if (e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value != "")

Still the trigger runs the code when I removed the value Approved/Duplicate/Rejected in the cell
The trigger is passing the code despite the condition is set to cell value !=null.